# Spring batch: how can I split records on a unique id?

Tags: spring-batch

I have a batch I'd column in my table and I have ids starting from 1 to 5, I want to process records for one batch I'd at a time. What approach I should follow so that I can process all the records for batch I'd 1 and then for batch I'd 2 and so on. Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: in the JPA reader, add to the query the batchID. then run the reader (actually run the whole job) n times (in your case n=5).

Comment: Do the batches need to be processed serially or can they be processed in parallel?

Comment: I need to process records serially.